# UIImageView not showing image in Xcode 6.0 iOS 7.1 and Later

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7.1

The images on UIImageView in my application is showing up in iOS 7.0 and earlier but not on iOS 7.1 and later. I Have used the old naming convention like imageName@2x.png and imageName.png.Also set it in the 
Code.But its not working at all.

When I replace the UIImageView with UIButton and set Image on it , it works fine but it would cause a lot of effort for me to change it everywhere in application.

Comment: show code for your UIIMageView.

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing .png extensions. If Asset Catalogs are enabled, no need to give image extensions